# Cordova android_asset real path

Tags: cordova, mobile

I want to open a PDF file but I must provide to 
`cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open` a real path (i.e. `/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf`) because a path like i.e. `file:///android_asset/www/starwars.pdf`
doesn't work and in fact the plugin returns **file not found**.

Now, where is into device `android_asset` dir? How is it real mapped?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have also installed the [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file), and assuming that your file is located inside your application at *www/starwars.pdf*, you could use **cordova.file.applicationDirectory** to point to your file:

```
var filePath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/starwars.pdf';
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(filePath, 'application/pdf', ...
```

> cordova.file.applicationDirectory - Read-only directory where the application is installed. (iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10)

**EDIT:** It seems that the only way to make this work is to transfer the file to the external storage and then perform the open operation on that file. In addition to cordova-plugin-file, you also need cordova-plugin-file-transfer. And cordova-plugin-file-opener2, of course.

```
    var filePath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + '/www/pdf-sample.pdf';        
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, function(entry) {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var targetFile = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + entry.name;

        fileTransfer.download(
            entry.toURL(),
            targetFile,
            function(entry) {
                cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                    targetFile,
                    'application/pdf', 
                    {
                        error : function(error){ alert('open error ' + JSON.stringify(error)) }, 
                        success : function(){ } 
                    } 
                );

            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
            }
        );
```

See a working version of a Cordova app that performs this operation in my Github repo: https://github.com/apandichi/demos/tree/master/pdf-file-open

Please note that you also need a pdf file viewer app to handle the 'open pdf' Intent.

Comment: No, that doesn't work because cordova.file.applicationDirectory returns file:///android_asset/ that not work with the plugin!

Comment: Any progress here? I can get it to give me file information on index.html but not file.pdf. It only throws error code 1 - on pdf and docx files

Comment: It seems that the only way to make this work is to transfer the file to the external storage and then perform the open operation on that file. See my updated answer.